# Connect to LDAP from website

Tags: php, ldap, centos7

The objective is to build a webpage to connect to an external LDAP server which allows the LDAP user to login view to my page.

I've developed a CentOS 7 server (LAMP setup) according to the instruction of http://www.servermom.org/complete-newbie-guide-to-build-centos-server-to-host-websites/

After done the setup, when I built a LDAP test page according to http://www.oit.uci.edu/idm/campusids/ldap-query-code-example-php/. I can successful connect to the external LDAP server but I cannot get any result from binding.

The telnet tells me the port can be connected.

Further to the above information, I have no idea whether it's CentOS setup issue, authentication issue from external LDAP server or scripting issue of PHP. Is there any idea where I can get the error and what suggestions to the issue?

Comment: ```ldap_connect``` will **always** return a valid handle but the actual connect is done on the first call to ```ldap_bind```. So if it's a connection issue it will occur then. Therefore I assume it's something like that. Can you add an ```var_Dump(ldap_error());``` right after the ```ldap_bind()``` and post it's results? It might make troubleshooting a bit easier ;)

Comment: @heiglandreas Thank you very much for your help. I've added and now I see string(25) "Can't contact LDAP server"

Comment: Hi. Try ```$ds=ldap_connect("ldap://ldap.service.uci.edu");``` in line 7 of the example-script. Which port did you check using telnet? Ldap runs on port 389 by default, so you should test ```telnet ldap.service.uci.edu 389``` to check for connectivity.

Comment: @heiglandreas Hi, I tried to connect to a ldap test server and information show as follow: http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/[root@reg-1 ~]# telnet ldap.forumsys.com 389
Trying 23.20.46.132...
Connected to ldap.forumsys.com.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: @heiglandreas I have two servers, one rent from public and the other build by myself. By testing the same php test page, the one rent from public seems ok but the one build by myself is saying "Can't contact LDAP". What might it causes?

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work with your own server while it works with a rented one. Code itself seems to be OK, otherwise it wouldn't work at all. If it's your own LDAP it might not be possible to do an anonymous bind ora firewall might block the requests from the webserver to the local ldap or, or or.... There's so many possibilities. :( Can you connect via ```ldapsearch``` to your own server? ```ldapsearch -h [ldapserver] uid=*``` should at least return something....

Comment: @heiglandreas I have setup SSL (443) to access my website. Is there any setup I have to take care in my Centos 7 for allowing my website to connect to external LDAP server?

Comment: SSL has nothing to do with it. It's how your browser connects to the webserver. But the webserver has issues connecting to the LDAP-Server. How did you setup the LDAP-Server? Is it running on the same machine as the webserver? How are you adressing the ldap-server?

Comment: @heiglandreas The LDAP-Server is provided by third party. I used http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/ for testing. If my server cannot contact with this LDAP server, while my rented server can contact his LDAP server, is it because my network blocks it or my Centos / Apache setup blocks it? What's the method I can get the error of this? Thank you so much for your experience sharing.

Comment: @heiglandreas Also, I can sure the LDAP server works because I can use the rented server to contact it. I just don't know if there is any specific setup for my local network setup / security setup to allow my own setup server to contact with the LDAP server.